# is something wrong with my stringtokenizer generated array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to make a simple Piano sheet compiler/player, where the user feeds the program a string of piano code ex "G E F D D G...etc", which is then broken by the stringtokenizer method and stored individually in a String array called code.
I've built a sheetPlayer method, which reads the array and based on multiple if statements would generate different sounds. everything seems ok but when I run the program no sound is played? and I accidentally found that if I was to directly initialize the code array ie code={"G","F"} the sound plays just find and im wondering if it's the stringtokenizer that is causing the problem?

```
public class PianoCompiler {

//public static Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
//using input user should be able to feed the program sheet code ex"G G D E" with space in between
//and it should be store into sheetCode String
public static String sheetCode="G E G G E G A G F E D E F ";
//code Array should be able to read sheetCode String and break and store it into single letter components
public static String[] code=sheetCode.split(" ");

public static void sheetPlayer()
{
    for(String key:code)
    {
        if(key=="G"){
            try
            {
                String gongFile = "/Users/Raed/Music/PianoSounds/g.wav";
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(gongFile);
                AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
            } catch(Exception e ){

            }

        }
        if(key=="F"){
            try
            {
                String gongFile = "/Users/Raed/Music/PianoSounds/f.wav";
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(gongFile);
                AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
            } catch(Exception e ){

            }

        }

        if(key=="E"){
            try
            {
                String gongFile = "/Users/Raed/Music/PianoSounds/e.wav";
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(gongFile);
                AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
            } catch(Exception e ){

            }

        }

        if(key=="D"){
            try
            {
                String gongFile = "/Users/Raed/Music/PianoSounds/d.wav";
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(gongFile);
                AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
            } catch(Exception e ){

            }

        }


        if(key=="C"){
            try
            {
                String gongFile = "/Users/Raed/Music/PianoSounds/c.wav";
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(gongFile);
                AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
            } catch(Exception e ){

            }

        }
        if(key=="B"){
            try
            {
                String gongFile = "/Users/Raed/Music/PianoSounds/b.wav";
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(gongFile);
                AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
            } catch(Exception e ){

            }

        }

        if(key=="A"){
            try
            {
                String gongFile = "/Users/Raed/Music/PianoSounds/a.wav";
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(gongFile);
                AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
            } catch(Exception e ){

            }

        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you reading in the user's input correctly then?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to compare `String`s against each other, use `String#equals(String)`. For instance

```
if ("E".equals(key))
```

See this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) as a reference.

Basically, if you compare instances using `==`, you just compare the reference value and not the content. Using `==`, two strings don't just have to **contain** the same string, they have to **be** the same object. The `String#equals(String)` method is implemented so that it just compares the content of the string instance (which is what you want).

You can also use `String#equalsIgnoreCase(String)` if you want the comparison to be case insensitive.

Comment: this worked! thanks man now I have a functional piano player, all I have to do now is figure out how to make the spaces in sheetcode count so it produces the right rythem :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Also for the person who downvoted: It is ok to downvote, but I would appreciate if you would tell me why, so I can improve this and future answers. :)